# Lead Landing Page in Visual Force

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites

Currently we have a lead landing page similar to the one shown below.

https://www.commbank.com.au/personal/home-loans/make-an-appointment.html

I am wondering whether I will be able to develop a similar aesthetically appealing landing page in Visualforce site.

**My Qs**

a) Is it possible for me to add jazzy UI stuff like CSS/jQuery etc in a Site ?

b) Will it be possible to expose this site to the internet without requiring any authentication ?. Basically we want this to be public facing without any restriction whats so ever for entering the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and yes. We have done this before. You will definitely be able to add css and jQuery into public site and open to everybody with no issue.

Answer (score 2):

> a) Is it possible for me to add jazzy UI stuff like CSS/jQuery etc in
>   a Site ?

Of course it is! See a demo site that I am working on [demo site](http://matw-pnc-developer-edition.na35.force.com/pncv4) & [find details here](https://salesforcemann.wordpress.com/2016/11/13/pet-project-create-parent-and-child-records-from-visualforce-page-for-any-salesforce-object-part-1/). It is beta but is using CSS and jQuery behind the scenes to make jazzy UI :)

> b) Will it be possible to expose this site to the internet without
>   requiring any authentication ?. Basically we want this to be public
>   facing without any restriction whats so ever for entering the data.

Refer to the [demo site](http://matw-pnc-developer-edition.na35.force.com/pncv4) site again.

Hope this helps.

On a side note, if you want to host a page developed in visualforce on your website, that can be done as well using iframes.